# Install Gtk 3 for python on mac

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, gtk3

I have installed python gtk3 using homebrew but it prints

> Warning: gtk+3-3.14.6 already installed

but when i try to import it in python

```
 from gi.repository import Gtk
```

it gives the error

> ImportError: No module named gi.repository

Please help.

Answer (score 10):

When I installed only `pygobject3` I got the following error when running a python script:

```
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 102, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
```

So it seems to me that you need to install both packages to get gtk3 with python bindings on Mac OS X:

```
brew install gtk+3 pygobject3
```

Comment: Just be careful that this will work with Homebrew Python3 only. It's separate from the python.org Python3 (/System/Library ...), if any.

Comment: Just went through this - if you want to use anything besides homebrew python3 this won't work. Here's a conda alternative https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701630/5824843

Answer (score 3):

Python bindings are not provided by GTK+. You need to install `pygobject3`.

Answer (score 3):

Installing using homebrew worked for me on 10.14:

```
brew install pygobject3 --with-python@2 gtk+3
```

References:

https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#macosx-logo-macos

Comment: no sure why someone unvote this. the --with-python@2 saved me some months ago. Today --with-pytohn@2 is not working anymore, it seems that the problem has been fixed.