# importing Gtk 3+ on mac for python 3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I am currently trying to develop a simple instant messenger with a GUI based in Gtk+3. I am using PyCharm on OS X. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098892/install-gtk-3-for-python-on-mac) post, but I already have gtk+3 and pygobject3 installed (I attempted to [again] install them with Homebrew but I got the messages: "gtk+3 3.22.19 is already installed" and "pygobject3 3.24.1_1 is already installed"). My code thus far:

```
import threading
import re

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

import gobject
import socket
import time
import datetime

gobject.threads_init()

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
```

My specific concerns are that in PyCharm, `require_version` is highlighted, saying "Cannot find reference 'require_version' in `__init__.py`, `repository` is highlighted saying "Cannot find reference 'repository' in `__init__.py`, and Gtk is underlined saying "Unresolved refernce 'Gtk'. I am unsure as to why, however, there is no protest when I type Gtk.Window or Gtk.Entry() [snipped]. My final concern is that `threads_init()` is highlighted, again saying "Cannot find reference 'threads_init()' in `__init__.py`. Could someone offer some insight as to what is wrong? I have done a good amount of research, but I have found very little that fits my particular situation: Mac, python3, and the two modules already installed.

Secondary question: The guide I am using to write this code is written in python2, and I will be writing in python3, so does anyone know of a good source that would indicate the differences in Gtk between python2 and python3 (what is new, maybe) so I might be able to write the correct python3 version of the gtk code?

Comment: The `gi.repository` imports generally don't work with tools like PyCharm because their contents are generated dynamically by C code, not defined in Python source files.

Comment: It actually works with pycharm these days you just need to right click and have it scan binary libraries or such.

Comment: Also nothing about Gtk is different in Python 2 vs Python 3 (sadly).

Comment: @TingPing Thank you for the answer to the secondary question! Could you elaborate on right-clicking to scan binary libraries? I attempted to do so, but did not find such an option in the menu box. I also regular-clicked on the highlighted portions: `gi.repository` produced an option "Generate stubs for binary module gi.repository.Gtk" upon clicking on the lightbulb that appeared, but selecting that option did not seem to change anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have it currently installed but I know that option has been successful in the past for me.